# Scrolling a horizontal UIScrollView in stepped increments?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, ios5

I have a UIScrollView that can be scrolled horizontally. The scrollable content is displayed in columns.

Is there a way to make the scrolling only move in stepped increments instead of pixels (i.e. move a column at a time).

Diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup there is:

```
yourScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Check the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) for more information.

> If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls. The default value is NO.

I suggest you may need to change your view structure to something like this:

```
+--------+
|        | <- UIView to hold your structure
+--------+

   +--+
   |  |    <- UIScrollView, clipsToBounds = NO, width = column.width
   +--+

+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  <- UIView columns
+--+--+--+
```

Center the `UIScrollView` horizontally and make sure that the `UIView` that contains the `UIScrollView` has a width that is a multiple of the width of the `UIScrollView`

Comment: Also i believe iOS SDK 5 added support to "suggest" locations in a scroll view ?

Comment: I can't see that in the docs :S Do you have a reference I can follow for that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken would not not just show one column at a time, I want to show multiple columns like in my example. Also to make it clear I'm not that bothered it scrolls like normal as long as it always stops on a whole column.

Comment: It would show multiple columns as you set the `UIScrollView` to not clip to bounds therefore it's content can be seen outside of it's bounds

Comment: Also users expect a scrollview to behave like a scrollview, to say "I'm not that bothered it scrolls like normal" will most likely lead to a below standard UX. I've used the technique above in two of my apps and have been very happy with it.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood how it would work, that sounds exactly what I wanted. I'll give it a go and see how I get on.

Comment: I've tried to implement what you suggested but I'm finding that the user can only interact with the UIScrollView and if they try to scroll the part that is visible outside of the UIScrollView's bounds it does not respond to events (i.e. scroll).

Comment: Forward the hit messages from the containing `UIView` to the `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

While I think paging is probably the right answer, it's not what you were asking, which was jerky scrolling (columns "at all times"). I believe you could provide a `-scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate and adjust contentOffset to the nearest column.

Answer (score 1):

If you target iOS 5.0, you can use the new UIScrollViewDelegate method scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset. This allows you to set the point where the scrolling animation will end after the user has stopped dragging the scroll view.

Comment: That sounds great unfortunately I need this to work in iOS4 and later.