# infinite scrolling +iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I want to implement a wheel like infinte scrolling Rating tool like the below image.

No i had taken an scrollview and set the orange image in scrollview

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
 UIImageView * headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_2.png"];    
 SCrl_Wheel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:headerImage.image];
 [SCrl_Wheel setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500,0)]; 
 [SCrl_Wheel setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO]; 
 Lbl_Rate.text=@"0";
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
}
```

Comment: I don't see any image..Use image button to upload image.

Comment: https://github.com/canopas/MarqueeScroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has an example project featuring infinite scrolling it's called [StreetScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102), which demonstrates how a `UIScrollView` subclass can scroll infinitely in the horizontal direction.
There is also an `UIScrollView` subclass on Github called [BAGPagingScrollView](https://github.com/bguest/BAGPagingScrollView), which is paging & infinite, but it has a few bugs you have to fix on your own, because it's not under active development (especially the goToPage: method leads to problems).
I hope this helps you.

Also  check this link for easy implementation they also have a sample code attached :)

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: Please check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But there is no paging in this scrolling,I had not added any image or label in uiscrollview.I had just added image itself in uiscrollview.So how did i do paging and manage paging becoz if i do paging then it might be possible to check for infinite scrolling condition

Comment: please check if this link would be helpful to you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246988/scrolling-a-horizontal-uiscrollview-in-stepped-increments

Comment: thank you very much But i had already gone this links.But my question is i dont want any paging in my scrollview.It should rotate like and wheel.I want a condition which give scrolling to my scroll at infinite way and also i am able to note the rating of (paging number) from 1-10